# SSL redirects clashes with session_start() and header("Location")

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

So I have a website that uses php sessions and php header location redirects. It is working fine without any problem. The problem starts when i try to edit the htaccess file in order to redirect all non https requests.
I have used the code below to send the redirects.

```
    # Force HTTPS and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above code works well in redirecting the non https requests but it then makes the session_start(); function and header location function to stop working..

I get the below error

```
**PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in  ** where i try to start the session.
```

Once I remove the ssl redirect everything works just fine.
I really want to redirect all non https requests without affecting the sessions and header location redirects.

I have tried to look for similar questions but no luck. Anyone with a solution please help

Comment: Ugly non-solution: have Apache handle sessions

Comment: The redirect in Apache should be happening before PHP is invoked, and I can't imagine a way for them to be related. I believe you when you say that removing that redirect makes the error to go away, but I'm also pretty certain that the error comes from something else in PHP. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: This is an error with your PHP code, not `.htaccess`. What if you request `https://www.example.com/...` directly?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your efforts.

I've been trying out any ssl redirect code on the web and the code below works perfectly without causing any error with the session_start and header location.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The code above actually redirects any non ssl requests without any problem... Can anyone try to explain why this code works fine but the other one doesn't. My assumption is that they both have to work because they does the same job

The code below causes errors and prevent session start and header location

```
# Force HTTPS and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301
```

Can any one who is familiar with apache try to compare why the 1st code works withouy causing an error but the second does work but causes errors

Comment: Those two code blocks don't do the same thing. Your original code block (that does "not work") also redirects non-www to www. Whereas the "working" code block redirects HTTP to HTTPS only and does not canonicalise the www subdomain. Maybe requesting the www subdomain over HTTPS is the problem? However, as stated in comments under the question, this is really an error with your application/PHP, not with Apache/.htaccess. (NB: In your answer you've chopped the last directive - as written that will certainly cause an error.)

Comment: As mentioned in my comment under your question... What if you request `https://www.example.com/...` directly? (ie. HTTPS + www)

Comment: @MrWhite the working code directs everything to https:// for example if i type example.com it will re direct to https://example instead of http. If i request https:// it redirect to https:// and removes the www

Comment: "If i request https:// it redirect to https:// and removes the www" - No, it doesn't. If you request HTTPS-anything then that rule does nothing (the first condition ensures that it is only processed when `HTTPS` is `off`). If you are seeing a redirect from `https://www` then something else is doing that, or you are seeing a cached redirect. HOWEVER, that is the opposite of the "non-working" rule, in that your original non-working rule explicitly ADDS the www, it doesn't remove it. That could also be contributing to your problem.

Comment: @MrWhite that is true , the non-working script adds the www but the working one removes the www if you happen to put it on your request. How ever they both redirect http to https which is what i want i dont want the security warning appearing just incase the user request using a http request